# which preposition fits better? "Introduce in" or "introduce into"?

Tags: prepositions

I want to write that a person implemented the economic system X into the British economy, but I don't know how to formulate the sentence. I need help. Which sentence is right?

1. "Person Y introduced the economic system X into the British economy."
2. "Person Y introduced the economic system X in the British economy."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about economics or what your X might be, but I suspect actually just "to" is more natural:
"Fiona Jones introduced the cap-and-trade system to the British economy."

Comment: I put the "X" in the sentence to keep it short and understandable. Thanks for the answer!!